# Pan Gesture with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avfoundation, normalization, avplayer, seek

This feature is really important to my app and would really like some help on it. Basically, I want to add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to a video player so that the user can fast forward/rewind the video with the gesture.

Apple has some sample code which uses Swift 3 and has the entire video player already created. The only thing missing is the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. This is the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVFoundationSimplePlayer-iOS/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016103

In `viewWillAppear` I added the gesture like so:

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture))
view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

This is the code that is working somewhat. It is currently scrubbing.

**The problem is that every time I start the pan gesture, the video    skips to the middle and I start from there. Instead of fast    forwarding/rewinding from where the video currently is, the pan    gesture skips the video to the middle and then allows me to fast    forward/rewind which is not good.**

```
func handlePanGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .began, .changed:
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        var horizontalTranslation = Float(translation.x)

        let durationInSeconds = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentItem!.asset.duration))

        // Using 275 as the limit for delta along x
        let translationLimit: Float = 275
        let minTranslation: Float = -1 * translationLimit
        let maxTranslation: Float = translationLimit

        if horizontalTranslation > maxTranslation {
            horizontalTranslation = maxTranslation
        }

        if horizontalTranslation < minTranslation {
            horizontalTranslation = minTranslation
        }

        let timeToSeekTo = normalize(delta: horizontalTranslation , minDelta: minTranslation, maxDelta: maxTranslation, minDuration: 0, maxDuration: durationInSeconds)
        print("horizontal translation \(horizontalTranslation) \n timeToSeekTo: \(timeToSeekTo)")

        let cmTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(timeToSeekTo), self.player.currentTime().timescale)
        player.seek(to: cmTime)

    default:
        print("default")
    }

}

func normalize(delta: Float, minDelta: Float, maxDelta: Float, minDuration: Float, maxDuration: Float) -> Float {

    let result = ((delta - minDelta) * (maxDuration - minDuration) / (maxDelta - minDelta) + minDuration)
    return result
}
```

Any help would be great - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your code. I used it, changed few lines, it's working well.

```
   @objc func handlePanGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
      switch sender.state {
       case .began, .changed:
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        let horizontalTranslation = Float(translation.x)

        let durationInSeconds = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentItem!.asset.duration))

        // normalize based on duration and width of the view
        let scale:Float = durationInSeconds / Float(self.view.frame.width) / 4
        // then you need to add the current time of player to avoid it starting from the middle.            
        let seekTime = horizontalTranslation * scale + Float((self.player.currentItem?.currentTime().seconds)!)

        let cmTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(Float(seekTime)), preferredTimescale: self.player.currentTime().timescale)
        player.seek(to: cmTime)
        print("horizontal translation \(horizontalTranslation) \n timeToSeekTo: \(seekTime)")

    default:
        print("default")
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

i've implemented `UIPanGesture` with `AVPlayer`, below is my working code `[swift 3]`.

```
func handleDraging(_ gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        let location = gesture.location(in: self.playerView)
        if gesture.state == .began {
            print("\n\n-->---> Panning.state = .began at Point.x = \(location.x)")
            self.playerLayer.player?.rate = 0
            self.stopTimer()
        }else if gesture.state == .changed {
            let valocity = gesture.velocity(in: self.playerView)
            print("\n\n-->---> Panning.state = .changed at Point.x = \(location.x)")
            let percentage = Double(location.x) / Double(self.playerView.frame.width)
            let currentTime = self.playerLayer.player!.currentTime()
            let currentSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentTime)
            var newSeconds = currentSeconds + percentage
            if valocity.x < 0 {
                newSeconds = currentSeconds - percentage
            }
            let newTime = CMTime(seconds: newSeconds, preferredTimescale: self.playerLayer.player!.currentTime().timescale)
            self.playerLayer.player?.seek(to: newTime, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
            let total = CGFloat(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.playerLayer.player!.currentItem!.asset.duration))
            let seconds = CGFloat(CMTimeGetSeconds(newTime))
            self.interval = Double(seconds)//here update your CurrentTimelabel.text .....

            let temp = seconds/total
            self.progress = Float(temp)//here update your UIProgressBar.progress .....
            print("\n\t-->Total Progress = \(temp)")
        }else if gesture.state == .ended || gesture.state == .failed || gesture.state == .recognized {
            gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.playerView)
            self.startTimer()
            self.playerLayer.player?.playImmediately(atRate: 1)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have calls such as stopTimer(), startTimer(). Where are they defined at?