# AVPlayer fast forward/backward skipping with pan gesture

Tags: ios, avplayer, uipangesturerecognizer, avplayerlayer

I've been bashing my head with an annoying glitch for the past two days and was hoping somebody could shed some light.

**Basic setup:** I have an AVPlayerLayer with a player, a pan gesture recognizer in the view and I want the user to be able to swipe their fingers back and forth and the video would seek accordingly.

**The catch:** I would like if the user lifts their finger and places it again,anywhere on the screen for the fast forward or backward to resume at the **exact** same frame where it left off and continue progressing from there.

I've seen these two questions:
[Pan Gesture with AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363371/pan-gesture-with-avplayer) and
[Pan to seek AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046946/pan-to-seek-avplayer)

I've tried Apple's suggestion here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1820/_index.html
as well, but the problem is that whenever I start a new pan gesture, the player jumps a few frames and then resumes.

My latest approach was to set the current time once the seek completion block finishes and then I try and append the new seek time to that.

Here is my setup:

```
self.item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:resource];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.item];
self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.playerLayer];
self.playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;

UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipe:)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

And my gesture recognizer handling:

```
- (void)swipe:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)paramRecognizer
{
    switch(paramRecognizer.state) {
      //  case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        {
            [self.player pause];
            
            CGPoint translation = [paramRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
            
            float horizontalTranslation = translation.x;
            
            float durationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentItem.asset.duration);
            
            //I'd like to be able to swipe across the whole view.
            float translationLimit = self.view.bounds.size.width;
            float minTranslation = 0;
            float maxTranslation = translationLimit;
            
            if (horizontalTranslation > maxTranslation) {
                horizontalTranslation = maxTranslation;
            }
            
            if (horizontalTranslation < minTranslation) {
                horizontalTranslation = minTranslation;
            }
            
        float timeToSeekTo = [self normalize:horizontalTranslation
                                 andMinDelta:minTranslation
                                 andMaxDelta:maxTranslation
                              andMinDuration:0
                              andMaxDuration:durationInSeconds];
            
            if(CMTIME_IS_VALID(self.currentTime)){
                float seconds = self.currentTime.value/self.currentTime.timescale;
        
                [self.player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds+timeToSeekTo, self.player.currentTime.timescale)
                        toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero
                         toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero completionHandler:^(BOOL finished)
                 {
                     if(finished)
                    self.currentTime = self.player.currentItem.currentTime;
                }];
            }
            else
            {
                [self.player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(timeToSeekTo,
                                                              self.player.currentTime.timescale) toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero
                         toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {
                             if(finished)
                    self.currentTime = self.player.currentItem.currentTime;
                }];
            }
            
        }
            break;
    }
}
```

The normalize method is this:

```
- (float)normalize:(float)delta
       andMinDelta:(float)minDelta
       andMaxDelta:(float)maxDelta
    andMinDuration:(float)minDuration
    andMaxDuration:(float)maxDuration
{
  float result = ((delta - minDelta) * (maxDuration - minDuration) / (maxDelta - minDelta) + minDuration);
  return result;
}
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Slightly confusing wording are you saying if you start paning at 3.00 seconds and say pan 2 px then lift, it should play at 5.00 or 3.00 again ?

Comment: @SeanLintern88It should play at 3.0 again, sorry cleared it up

Comment: OK just to clarify, you would be at 3.0, being panning and scrub back/forth, then on .end revert back to 3.0 ? But during scrub video would smoothly go back/ forth based on the pan ? If so what exactly is this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` save `CMTime` through from `AVPlayer` then do your delta change panning, then on `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` just seek back to the original saved time?

Just a note for smoother seeking do not pause the video, set the rate to 0.

Comment: You are indeed correct, i noticed the problem after reading your comment, if you have a look at my sample code, I was setting the initial seek time under UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged rather than UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan, hence why I was seeing an initial jerk when the user began the swipe.

Comment: Also use the rate to pause not pause, this makes seeking much more fluid.

Comment: Re. the pause/rate difference, just to mention that as of today [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1387895-pause) say that they're exactly the same thing: 
*Calling this method is the same as setting the rate to 0.0.*